# Print and Clear in C without libraries

Tags: c, printing

I'm trying to develop a *Operative System*.
It works, but the function "print" that I've written has an error:
If I print two Strings only one will be displayed, and the command `\n` does not work.
My questions are: 
How to use the command `\n`?
 and
How to create the function clear without using libraries?
This is the function print:

```
void print(char* message, int color)
{
    char* mem = (char*)(0xb8000);
    while(*message != 0)
    {
        *mem = *message;
        mem++;
        message++;
        *mem = (char*)color;
        mem++;
    }
}
```

PS It Works, but the problem is that if I use the function print two times (with or whitout `\n` it prints me only the second part.

Comment: Please don't shout in bold.

Comment: "*`... (0xb8000);`*" how long I haven't seen this Magic Number any more ... :-)

Comment: you're *always writing the string starting from the upper-left corner*. You're supposed to **write code** that handles a) cursor position, b) characters such as `\n` and so on...

Comment: @coderredoc: That's the base address of the memory of an ancient (?) video card.

Comment: @alk.: Yes just checked it out...in fact really I forgot ..those color monitors etc etc

Comment: Please describe the effect of the "clear" function you want.

Comment: Essential parts are missing from your question notably what lies at address 0xb8000, and in what format. As an old dinausaur, I can remember it should be the screen text buffer address on a PC system in real mode, one byte for the char, the latter for the color. But it used to depend on the screen size and available colors. Without that info your question is hard to understand

Comment: @shawn: I disagree, this question has nothing to do with how an OS works. For anyone familiar with this method of character placement, it is obvious what OP is ... well, not even doing *wrong*, but simply not DOING. Which suggests that OP does not understand the background principles of the task and the "question" is a plain 'you write codez for me?'

Comment: There is a bit more to an OS than a real-mode screen driver...

Answer (score 1):

To simulate a line break you probably need to write as many spaces to the video memory as there are characters left in the current line. Hence, you need to remember how many characters you wrote to the current line.

The same applies for scrolling. You need to copy the memory in a way that the last line on the screen becomes blank again.

Answer (score 1):

You should have some context of the printing function.

eg: you should have a global(or static) variable to remember your last printed position of the video output memory.

something like:

```

```
static int last_pos = 0;
void print(char* message, int color)
{
    char* mem = (char*)(0xb8000);
    mem += last_pos * 2;
    while(*message != 0)
    {
        if(*message == '\n') {
            set the mem to next line and calculate the new last_pos
            continue;
        }
        *mem = *message;
        mem++;
        message++;
        *mem = (char*)color;
        mem++;
        last_pos ++;
        if (last_pos >= max_video_buffer) {
             move content the buffer to scroll the screen
             or
             simply reset the last_pos and mem to restart from top-left.
        }
    }
}
```

```

when do clearing: just fill the whole video output memory to empty and reset the `last_pos`